# nginx ingress controller goes into CrashLoopBackOff status after adding - -default-ssl-certificate=default/certificate-name flag

Tags: kubernetes, lets-encrypt, nginx-ingress

I'm trying to add *SSL certificate* from letsencrypt on my *GKE* cluster. My Certificate status is *ready* but when I add the flag `--default-ssl-certificate=default/certificate-name` in the nginx ingress controller deployment file, *deployment.yaml* and apply, the *pod* crashes.

Anyone could help?

Comment: the only change you are supposed to do is to mark the certificate name in the ingress rule files, don't change the ingress deployment & svc files. Verfication will be done by cert-manager

Comment: Can you add the nginx ingress logs?